# mysql select latest data based on date

Tags: mysql

```
id | status  |  dateCreate
1  |   0     |  2020-02-15 15:41:06
2  |   1     |  2020-02-18 15:41:06
1  |   1     |  2020-02-18 15:41:06
2  |   0     |  2020-02-25 15:41:06
1  |   1     |  2020-03-01 15:41:06
4  |   1     |  2020-03-18 15:41:06
3  |   1     |  2020-03-19 15:41:06
7  |   0     |  2020-03-20 15:41:06
5  |   1     |  2020-03-21 15:41:06
4  |   0     |  2020-03-21 15:41:06
8  |   1     |  2020-03-22 15:41:06
4  |   1     |  2020-03-23 15:41:06
```

this is my sample table what i wanted to do is to get the latest status which is 1 for each id
so based on the table what i want to be the result was this:

```
id |  status  |  dateCreate
1  |   1      |  2020-03-18 15:41:06
4  |   1      |  2020-03-18 15:41:06
3  |   1      |  2020-03-19 15:41:06
5  |   1      |  2020-03-21 15:41:06
8  |   1      |  2020-03-22 15:41:06
```

since id 2 latest status was 0

and this is my sample query which doesn't get what exactly i want since it also gets the id 2 since it has a status of 1 before. what i wanted to be the result was to get the lastest status based on dateCreate with status of 1

```
SELECT A.id,A.status, MAX(A.dateCreate)
        FROM (SELECT id, status, dateCreate
              FROM table status = 1) A GROUP BY A.id ORDER BY A.dateCreate desc
```

Comment: then i cant get the id 2 if the status becomes 1 also.

Comment: expected result is...???

Comment: i update my question and add other data for better understanding

Comment: Note that, by convention, an `id` column is normally an 'identity' column, meaning its value cannot be duplicated.

Comment: recheck the first two rows of your expected result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join and test

```
select t.*
from t
join (select id, max(datecreate) maxdate from t group by id) s on s.id = t.id and s.maxdate = t.datecreate 
where t.status = 1
```

Comment: Note that this assumes (not unreasonably), that (id,datecreate) is unique

Comment: it worked. thanks. i also tried a different query which result was same as yours. here's mine `select id,status from table where id in (SELECT max(id) from table group by id) and status = 1`

Comment: Your query produces 4 rows (based on your original data) ?